# Use accesor getAttribute in query model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Post, and I have:

```
protected $appends = ['reviews_count'];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function () {
        static::updateRanks();
    });
}

public function reviews() {
   return $this->hasMany(Review:class);
}

public static function updateRanks()
{
    DB::statement("UPDATE posts set `rank` = (SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at) ORDER BY points desc, created_at asc ) FROM (select * from posts) as posts_rankings)))");
}

public function getReviewsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->reviews()->active()->count();
}
```

I need in `CONCAT(points, '_', created_at)` add a `reviews_count` and next do `ORDER BY points desc, reviews_count desc, created_at asc`. How I can do this? If I add, I get error: `unknown column reviews_count..`.

Comment: Did you add it in your `$fillable = [...]` array?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, butI think that the problem is your database statement. The `reviews_count` is a computed attribute that is generated in the model, but your are trying to use it on a raw DB statement (where that attribute/column doens't exist yet).

Answer (score 0):

When you add an appended property, it's a kind of magic property laravel appends each time you have an eloquent mode instance.

But, your table schema dos not literally has `reviews_count` column.

You can get that count from SQL query using join or subquery if thats what you really need. However, having such update functions with raw statements is not the best practice to follow. Eventually it becomes hard to read and debug. I will suggest you to structure it as well as you can. Don't worry, we all have been there :)