# Pass attribute in query Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have model Post, and I have:

```
protected $appends = ['reviews_count'];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function () {
        static::updateRanks();
    });
}

public function reviews() {
   return $this->hasMany(Review:class);
}

public static function updateRanks()
{
    DB::statement("UPDATE posts set `rank` = (SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', created_at) ORDER BY points desc, created_at asc ) FROM (select * from posts) as posts_rankings)))");
}

public function getReviewsCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->reviews()->active()->count();
}
```

I need in `CONCAT(points, '_', created_at)` add a `reviews_count` and next do `ORDER BY points desc, reviews_count desc, created_at asc`. Attribute `reviews_count` is not working in query. I need add subquery or join. How I can do this? I tried:

```
DB::statement("UPDATE posts set `rank` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE post_id = posts_rankings.id) as reviews_count, (SELECT FIND_IN_SET( CONCAT(points, '_', reviews_count, '_', created_at), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(points, '_', reviews_count, '_' created_at) ORDER BY points desc, reviews_count desc, created_at asc ) FROM (select * from posts) as posts_rankings)))");
```

But this get me error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reviews_count`

Comment: I believe you have asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54640309/use-accesor-getattribute-in-query-model-laravel/54640790#54640790) before and it has answers

Comment: @MihirBhende this is my friend, I ask about query, how correctly I can do subquery